# combine two n dimensional arrays using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 arrays of shape (2500, 32, 32, 3) each.
I want to combine them into an array of (5000, 32, 32, 3)
How do I go about it?

Comment: numpy concatenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy's rowstack function.

```py
c = np.row_stack((a,b))
print(c.shape)   # (5000, 32, 32, 3)
```